# Creating a formula

Tags: induction, dynamical-systems

> Let $f :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = 2x+1$. Find the first $4$ iterates of $x_0 =0$ under $f$. Find a formula for the $n$th iterate $x_n = f^n(0)$. Use induction to prove that your formula holds.
>   Blockquote

So far I have that:

$$f(x) = 2x + 1$$

- $x_0 = 0$
- $x_1 = f(0) = 2(0) + 1 = 1$
- $x_2 = f(1) = 2(1) + 1 = 3$
- $x_3 = f(2) = 2(3) + 1 = 7$
- $x_4 = f(3) = 2(3) + 1 = 15$

I can see therefore that $$x_n = 2n - 1 $$

My problem is proving by induction. I can prove it for one example: 
$x_1 = 2(1) -1 = 1$ which is true.

But I am not too sure about the second part of the inductive proof. So far I have:
$$x_{n+1} = 2(n+1) -1 = 2n + 2 -1 = (2n -1) + 2 $$

Any idea how I would finish off this?

Comment: Your formula is wrong. For instance, when $n=4$, $x_4=7$.

Answer (score 2):

Your theory is (I hope) $X_n=2^n-1$.  You have shown the base case.  For the inductive step, you assume it is true for $k$, so $X_k=2^k-1$  Now compute $X_{k+1}$ from $X_k$ using the definition.  You should be able to show that $X_{k+1}=2^{k+1}-1$